# Is there an investment account where I can owe taxes only if the net of capital gain and dividend payment is positive?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, dividends

I am planning to open an account to trade or a fund, and I am looking for a very specific legal structure.

Basically, I am looking for a legal structure that allows me to receive the gross dividend of the stock (US or European stocks), with no withholding tax. At the end of the fiscal year I will pay the taxes for my total gains, including the dividends.

For example, if the stocks perform 10%, and from the dividends I get 4%, I will pay taxes for the whole 14%. But if the stocks perform -10% and the dividends 4%, I don't pay taxes, as my net result is negative.

I am living in UK, but I may be able to open the account (or the fund structure) in other countries.

Comment: Tax questions require a country tag.

Comment: In many countries, the "performance" of stocks by 10% (meaning that the stock price increased by 10%) does not create a taxable event; only _realized gains_ (which would occur when you _sell_ the stock) are taxable. Which is _your_ country?

Comment: You seem to be making up your own tax laws.

Comment: Have edited it. I am residing in UK, but can open the account (or the fund structure) in other countries.

Scott, is not about making my laws, is about finding the right structure (if it exist). Maybe a SIPP? Maybe a mutual fund?

Comment: Not possible. All trading accounts give you net dividends. Else what is stopping you from closing the account and moving to a different broker, just before the financial year ends. The tax man will visit the broker and they will have to pay out of their pocket.

Comment: A SIPP or an ISA will let you trade tax-free in general but they come with their own restrictions on what you can do with them. You might want to look into CFDs (Contracts for Difference) or TRSs (Total Return Swaps).

Comment: Hi Ganesh, what you mention sounds very interesting. I have been speaking with a couple of providers on CFD, but the dividend that you receive is net. Do you know any particular provider that gives CFD or TRS with gross dividends?

Answer (score 3):

No such account exists as capital gains aren't realized until holdings are sold.

For example:

1. Year starts.
2. Buy $1000 of XYZ
3. Receive dividend of $40
4. XYZ raises price to $1100
5. Year end - you own the same amount of stock initially purchased.

OR

1. Year starts.
2. Buy $1000 of XYZ
3. Receive dividend of $40
4. XYZ lowers price to $900
5. Year end - you own the same amount of stock initially purchased.

Both scenarios would result in you owing the appropriate taxes on a $40 gain from the dividends.   The $100 gain or $100 loss that isn't realized (you haven't sold the stock) isn't accounted for until the year of sale.

Comment: Alex, I understand that this is the normal procedure. But I know that certain structures (e.g. ISA account) allow you to reduce your taxes, and also the dividend taxes. I wanted to find such a structure.

Comment: The ISA reduces your tax due on capital gains also, but you would only see the benefit when you realize those capital gains.  Paper gains (or losses) are not taxed.

Comment: How does the ISA treat the dividend tax (on UK stocks and foreign stocks, understanding foreign as non-UK)?

Comment: I would ask that as a separate question to give it the best attention.

Answer (score 1):

Income and Capital are taxed separately in the uk.

You probably can't get dividends paid  gross even in ISA's you pay the basic rate of tax on dividends only higher rate tax payers get tax benefit from dividends.

What you could do is invest in splits (Spilt capital investment trusts ) in the share class where all the return comes as capital and use up some of your yearly CGT allowance that way.